# Python date time parsing

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

Why is this failing:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(
        date_string, ' %A %d %B %Y : %I:%M %p')
ValueError("time data ' Tuesday 08 September 2020 :  00:07 AM' does not match format ' %A %d %B %Y : %I:%M %p'")
```

when this works:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(' Wednesday 02 September 2020 :   2:54 AM', ' %A %d %B %Y : %I:%M %p')
```

I think it must have to do with the `00` hours, but what it is exactly I do not know.

Comment: Because the `00` in `00:07` is not a valid time for `%I`, which is "Hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number [01,12]".

Comment: Would it be 12:07 AM then? I'm bad with the AM / PM system.

Comment: Yes, it would be 12:07 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) docs:

> - %H Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number. 00, 01, …, 23
> - %I Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number. 01, 02, …, 12

So you would need input like `12:07 am` for the time to be valid (there is no 0 o'clock in a 12 hour clock)

```
>> datetime.datetime.strptime(' Tuesday 01 September 2020 : 12:07 AM', ' %A %d %B %Y : %I:%M %p')
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 1, 0, 7)
```

Or use `%H` for 24 hour clock, in which case you'd likely want to drop the `%p` since it's meaningless in this case

```
>> datetime.datetime.strptime(' Tuesday 01 September 2020 : 00:07', ' %A %d %B %Y : %H:%M')  
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 1, 0, 7)
```